# Setup SNI/SSL in cPanel

Tags: ssl, cpanel, sni

I am looking to setup SNI under cPanel, and while I know it's not directly supported just yet:
http://forums.cpanel.net/f145/case-46856-sni-server-name-indicator-ssl-support-cpanel-83661.html

That doesn't mean it can't be done as far as I'm aware.

Does anyone know a guide or have any advice as where to look to set it up?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-------- UPDATE --------

I found this link which details how to set it up on Apache but have been told that cPanel overrides the config files:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/configure-apache-to-support-multiple-ssl-sites-on-a-single-ip-address/987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHM 11.38 now supports SNI:
http://blog.cpanel.net/ssl-improvements-for-cpanel-whm/

> **Server Name Indicator (SNI)**
>
> Currently, it’s common for each SSL Certificate to require its own
>   dedicated IP address. The cost of this address is typically being
>   passed down to the end user.
>
> SNI is able to change this paradigm by indicating what hostname the
>   client is connecting to at the start of the handshake process. This
>   allows a server to have multiple certificates all installed on the
>   same IP address. Users on shared servers, that support SNI, will be
>   able to install their own certificates and bypass the need for a
>   dedicated address. While this saves on the cost of the dedicated IP
>   address, this also helps reduce the need for extra addresses.
>
> In order to experience the full benefit of SNI in cPanel & WHM 11.38,
>   an operating system that supports this functionality will be needed as
>   well. CentOS 6 is a prime example of such an operating system.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I've seen, using mod_gnutls.
http://blog.dembowski.net/2011/10/28/sni-on-centos-5-6-mod_gnutls/

Apparently installing an updated OpenSSL can break lots of other tools and if you install a separate copy you still have to compile Apache to use that one, which breaks the autoupdater.

Comment: The issue is not SNI on CentOS, it's SNI in cPanel, it doesn't inherently support it, I didn't see anything about working in cPanel.

Comment: The link you provided to techrepublic requires OpenSSL 0.9.8f which cPanel doesn't provide/support so that's why I offered the alternative.